# Change Material-UI theme dynamically?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Can anyone guide me on how to change the theme type dynamically in Child component using Material-UI?

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    type: "dark"
  }
});

    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
         <CssBaseline/>
         <Container className={classes.container}>
             <OrderBook/>
         </Container>
    </ThemeProvider>
```

And I'd like to switch the theme in deep child component.
I know can send the props to child component to change the theme. But I think there will be easier way with MUI

Comment: As I understand it, you want to have different themes for different child components? Or change the current theme from within a child component?

Comment: I'd like to change the current theme from within a child component.

Comment: Either way as far as i know, you would have to send some information upwards to the parent component that holds `ThemeProvider` so I think simply tackle it with the props solution. Unless anyone more experienced than me offers a more smart solution :)